# Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method error in razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, view-components

When using view components in my views I am getting this error which doesn't make sense.  When I open up a view that uses a view component (calling the tag helper for said view component), I am seeing an error that I can't figure out how to solve in the Error List Section in Visual Studio..

The error only shows in the error list if a cshtml file is open.. If I close the cshtml file(s) the error(s) disappear.. The error is duplicated for each cshtml file that is open..

The error never prevents the application from building and it renders the view component as expected..

This error is just visually annoying and possibly misleading... Is there a way to get rid of this?  Am I doing something that is not correct to make this error show?  Is this a Visual Studio Bug?

Edit: My application has many view components.. Often I call other view components from within view component views.. This seems to be what is causing the error but I don't understand why... also even though many view components do this.. The Error is only shown for one view component but duplicated for each cshtml file that is open... If I comment out the line that is calling the view component tag helper from within the view component view the error is now shifted to some other view component that does the same and is still duplicated for each view.. very confusing!

Any help is appreciated Thanks..

Error:

```
Error       Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component 'AspNetCore.Views_Shared_Components_Some_SomeViewComponent'.  SomeWebProject  C:\Src\SomeWebProjectFolder\Views\Shared\Components\Some\SomeViewComponent.cshtml   1
```

ViewComponent Implementation classes -->

```cs
//Base View Component Class
public abstract class BaseViewComponent<TViewModel> : ViewComponent
    where TViewModel : IViewComponentViewModel
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(TViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel.ViewName, viewModel);
    }
}

//Derived View Component Class
public class SomeViewComponent : BaseViewComponent<SomeViewComponentViewModel>
{ }

//View Component View Model Implementation for SomeViewComponent
public class SomeViewComponentViewModel : IViewComponentViewModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    //Below properties are implementations of IViewComponentViewModel.. 
    //Shared/Components/Some/ folder structure to find the view.. 
    public string ViewComponentName => "Some";
    //view named "SomeViewComponent.cshtml"
    public string ViewName => nameof(SomeViewComponent);
}
```

SomeViewComponent.cshtml (calls nested view component)-->

```html
@model SomeViewComponentViewModel
<span><vc:some-other view-model="Model.SomeProperty" /></span>
```

Some View that uses SomeViewComponent -->

```html
@model SomeViewModel

<vc:some view-model="Model.SomeViewComponentViewModel" />
```

Comment: Can you share a mini repro code sample to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: nope.. you can just create any project and demonstrate it for yourself.. .